# subfigure correct labeling

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I use the label command to get a) and b) next to my pictures. AucTeX claims these are all duplicate global labels. I guess I misunderstood the subfigure.

```
\subfigure[][]{%
  \label{a}
  }%
% later in the document
\subfigure[][]{%
  \label{a}
  }%
```

Was it a mistake to annotate with `label`?

Please do not answer with alternatives for subfigure. When I start my next document I will try something different, but I have to fix it this time.

Comment: You mean that for each figure with a subfigure you always start with `\label{a}` then `\label{b}` and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\label` does not produce a visible label it is the internal key (identifier) a symbolic name for the figure so that you can cross reference it from elsewhere in the document with `ref{a}` . `\ref` will generate the actual figure number as used by the figure labeled `a`. Clearly this only works if there is only one such figure.